# Launch Android widget via ADB

Tags: android, widget, adb

I would like to launch the Android weather widget.

The package is:

```
com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather
```

I tried many different versions of

```
adb shell am start .....
```

but was not successful.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: @Firelord: Unfortunately no answers yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command, for starting an activity in adb shell using a component name, is:

`am start -n package/activity`

So, in your case specifically, simply launch adb shell and enter the command as follows:

```
> am start -n "com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather/com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.weather.detail.DetailActivity"
```

If you want to start this in Android programmatically, you may do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setComponent(new
ComponentName("com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather", "com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.weather.detail.DetailActivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 

if (intent != null && intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. I used the adb shell command, but have not tried your programmatically solution.